# Cache server - store 100 million 100kb objects

Tags: caching

which open-source software you would use (not java, linux compatible) to cache 100 million around 100kb objects, which got different time for expiration (TTL). I did it before in files (horrible), mysql (still not good), redis (little better), mongodb (ok, but...)

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

10 000 000 000 kilobytes = 9 536.74316 gigabytes (If I'm not wrong - double-check it yourself!)

You are saying "cache" so I'm going to assume you want a fast, in-memory cache.

So first and foremost, you need a RAM large enough to cache this, or multiple machines which add up to that amount of RAM and then shard between them.

Then it depends on the nature of caching. For a very simple key-value caching, you can go with Memcache. If you want more operations, like sets, sorted sets, object hashing, etc., then Redis may be a very good choice (see [data types](http://redis.io/topics/data-types) and [commands](http://redis.io/commands) of Redis). But don't forget to turn off the persistence in Redis, in order for it to behave like a non-persistent cache.

One gotcha to look out for - if you use a single program to cache these 9 GB of data, it will need to be a 64-bit process. Which means that the 64-bit pointer overhead may require substantial extra gigabytes to store your data. If it's easy to separate your keys into shards, e.g. based on hashing and a modulo operation (e.g. if your keys would be naturally well distributed using this or other sharding algorithm), then your best way is to use multiple 32-bit instances (you can run 32-bit programs even on 64-bit machines) to store the data (either on a single machine, if the RAM is large enough, or split across multiple machines). There is currently work in progress on Redis cluster, and I'm sure for memcached there must be tools that do this as well. Or you can shard directly in your client.

Also, one thing to mention, if this cached data could actually serve as your main data, then you may not have to have two copies of them - one in the DB and one in the cache - because you can use the persistence options that Redis offers (only-append log file and snapshotting), and you can have Redis as your main database.

Comment: I think your calculation of "9 536.74316 GB" is correct, which would make the size over 9TB, not 9GB...which presents a hardware challenge by today's memory standards.

Comment: as you can see, 9TB is challenge to have in RAM. I meant file-cache, do you know anything other the redis or mongo ? Thanks.

Comment: @TimMedora: thanks, I have read that wrong after myself, 9TB it is:)